# Starting the numbering of the bibliography at a different number than one?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, numbering

I am using BibTeX.  I would like to start numbering of the bibliography at a later number than one.  I could redefine `\thebibliography` in the preamble (an often cited 'solution').  A minimal example (`bla.tex`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\oldthebibliography=\thebibliography
\let\oldendthebibliography=\endthebibliography
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]{%
    \oldthebibliography{#1}%
    \setcounter{enumiv}{77}%
}{\oldendthebibliography}

\begin{document}
This is a test.  Some newer thing
about a canonical quantum gravity approach\cite{rovelli2004}.
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{biblio-physics}
\end{document}
```

The bibliography file, `biblio-physics.bib`, only contains one entry:

```
@BOOK{rovelli2004,
    author = {Rovelli, Carlo},
    citeulike-article-id = {469595},
    howpublished = {Hardcover},
    isbn = {0521837332},
    keywords = {quantum\_gravity},
    month = {November},
    posted-at = {2007-05-06 15:26:19},
    priority = {3},
    publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
    address = {Cambridge},
    title = {Quantum Gravity},
    url = {http://www.amazon.ca/exec/obidos/redirect?tag=citeulike09-20\&amp;path=ASIN/0521837332},
    year = {2004}
}
```

This should start numbering at 78, but, using a minimal example with TeX Live 2012, I get an error from `pdflatex`:

```
marco@gluon test $ ls
biblio-physics.bib  bla.tex
marco@gluon test $ pdflatex bla
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012/Debian)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./bla.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, du
tch, nynorsk, bokmal, indonesian, esperanto, coptic, welsh, irish, interlingua,
 serbian, serbianc, slovenian, friulan, romansh, estonian, romanian, armenian, 
uppersorbian, turkish, afrikaans, icelandic, kurmanji, loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
No file bla.aux.

LaTeX Warning: Citation `wald1984' on page 1 undefined on input line 10.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `rovelli2004' on page 1 undefined on input line 11.

No file bla.bbl.
[1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./bla.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.

 )</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx10.pfb></us
r/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on bla.pdf (1 page, 24290 bytes).
Transcript written on bla.log.
marco@gluon test $ bibtex bla
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2012/Debian)
The top-level auxiliary file: bla.aux
The style file: plain.bst
Database file #1: biblio-physics.bib
marco@gluon test $ pdflatex bla
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012/Debian)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./bla.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, du
tch, nynorsk, bokmal, indonesian, esperanto, coptic, welsh, irish, interlingua,
 serbian, serbianc, slovenian, friulan, romansh, estonian, romanian, armenian, 
uppersorbian, turkish, afrikaans, icelandic, kurmanji, loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)) (./bla.aux)

LaTeX Warning: Citation `wald1984' on page 1 undefined on input line 10.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `rovelli2004' on page 1 undefined on input line 11.

(./bla.bbl

! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.3 \bibitem{rovelli2004}

?
```

Without the redefinition of `\thebibliography`, the document compiles fine, but of course starting the bibliography items at one.

All files can be found here: http://d-brane.net/pub/StackExchange/TeX_100184/

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: We need a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), because a small test doesn't show problems.

Comment: @egreg, minimal working example added.

Comment: I get no error from the MWE

Comment: @Marco, I concur with egret. Using your code and a file biblio-physics.bib that contains
    `@Article{wald1984,
    author = {wald},
    title = {title1},
    journal = {journal1},
    year = {1984},
    }
    
    @Article{rovelli2004,
    author = {rovellu},
    title = {title2},
    journal = {journal2},
    year = {2004},
    }`

I don't get any error and the numbering starts at 78, as you want.

Comment: is it at all possible that you didn't run latex twice after changing the definition that resets the initial value of `enumiv`?

Comment: After running pdflatex after bibtex, I get the error.  I added all the steps (pdflatex; bibtex; pdflatex) with output in the main question field.

Comment: I still can not reproduce your error. Are you 100% sure that your bla.tex and biblio-physics.bib are the same you posted?

Comment: @mafp, yes the files are identical.  I also tried with TeX Live 2011 and TeX Live 2012 on Fedora.  I get the same error.  The most obvious thing is that the example here and on my computer are not identical, but they really are.

Comment: Odd. Maybe you should post your bla.bbl file, there seems to be an error. Did you modify `plain.bst`, by any chance?

Comment: Here are all relevant files: http://d-brane.net/pub/StackExchange/TeX_100184/

Comment: @MarcovanHulten In the `bla.tex` file you have spurious characters in the redefinition of `thebibliography`. Retype it without using TAB for indenting lines, but only spaces. You'll see that the error will vanish.

Comment: @egreg et al., this solved the problems.  It were indeed characters that LaTeX couldn't handle.  They were no TABs though (those always convert to four spaces in my editor), but some kind of funny spaces copied from a website (possibly SE).  So the lesson is: always be careful with copy'n'paste!  Thank you all for the help.

Comment: @MarcovanHulten I voted for closing as too localized, as it's not a general problem.